# Using Authentication in Nuxtjs while token stored in cookie

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have stored JWT token in the cookie. How to use nuxt  js authentication. Should I use cookie authentication ??

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.